# Translate HTML file with Poedit

Tags: php, html, localization, poedit

I have an html file as shown below:

```
<li>
    <a href="">
        <i class="ic6 icon big"></i>
        {{_(Settings)}}
    </a>
</li>
```

I want to translate Settings with poedit software, but when I click Synchronization in the software it does not recognize the text.

I added html files extensions like this:

*.php;*.php3;*.php4;*.phtml;*.html;*.htm

In File --> Preferences, but it still does not recognize it... How do I allow html to recognize my text like this: _(text) ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks at the specific error message Poedit throws. If you can make sense out of the error message you will be able to rectify it too.

You can Email help@poedit.net and describe the problem(https://poedit.net/support).

Hope this helps!

Happy Coding.

Comment: Try playing with the underscore position in html (_{{(Settings)}}). Also try to see if anything else is getting translated at all like a know text that is definitely working fine.

Comment: the underscore dont belong to translate its my template reconize... the poedit need to recognize the _(Settings) but its not

Answer (score 0):

This is a complicated problem. I have been working on a solution, and have come up with a method that combines PHP, HTML, and JS to make this work. I came to this solution in order to write a PHP-less website (so that it can run within PhoneGap), using a javascript-based i18n library, while still utilizing Poedit to manage translations.

I posted a solution to this problem on this thread: [Scan html files in poedit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33145314/scan-html-files-in-poedit)